# MySQL remove characters between two brackets

Tags: mysql, sql

I am going through some data in MySQL and I need to remove some information from a column which looks likes this.

```
**sometext** (something else)
```

The data is inconsistent unfortunately; not all of the data follows this structure, some of it just has the first part.

```
**sometext**
```

So I need a way to remove everything between the brackets and then the brackets themselves in order to just leave the `**sometext**` part.

Comment: What have you tried? Does it need to be a one-time only solution (so maybe you can write some small program to progress the table)?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/string-functions.html find the first bracket then the second after all cut off as you need.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use this solution:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET    txt = REPLACE(txt, SUBSTRING(txt, LOCATE('(', txt), LENGTH(txt) - LOCATE(')', REVERSE(txt)) - LOCATE('(', txt) + 2), '')
WHERE  txt LIKE '%(%)%'
```

Keep in mind that due to the limitation of MySQL's minimal regex support, this will not work for *(will return blank)*:

```
(replacetext1) keepthistext1 (replacetext2) keepthistext2 (replacetext3)
```

...if you want to keep `keepthistext1` and `keepthistext2` since it will remove *everything* between the first opening parenthesis and the last closing parenthesis.

[*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d47fb/1)

Comment: @TomChew-headMillard see my more robust solution I just posted (w/ new SQLFiddle Demo). Now it will keep anything ***AFTER*** the last closing parenthesis.

Answer (score 3):

you could try using function `SUBSTRING_INDEX`.
The syntax is:

```
SUBSTRING_INDEX(str,delim,count)
```

In this case it could be something like:

```
UPDATE tbl
SET    txt = (SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(txt, '(', 1));
```

This would help, though i have not checked the query.
For further reference on this function you can look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function%5Fsubstring-index)

Answer (score 2):

MySQL doesn't support regular expressions, so the only way will be to use an external program written in PHP etc, or use stored procedures.

Comment: is there any way of splitting the data by a blank space checking that the 2nd part doesn't return black then running an update query or would it still be easier to write some php?

Comment: You can do string operations without regex.

Comment: @edze of course, but in this case, you can't remove arbitrary content between two delimiters without regex.

Comment: i just need to remove all the data between the brackets, if that changes anything.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a user-defined function that does it and works with multiple bracket pairs in the string:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE FUNCTION REMOVE_BRACKETS(input TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin)
  RETURNS TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin
  BEGIN
    DECLARE output TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin DEFAULT '';
    DECLARE in_brackets BOOL DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE length INT;

    IF(input IS NULL)
    THEN
      RETURN NULL;
    END IF;

    WHILE(TRUE) DO
      SET length = LOCATE(CASE WHEN in_brackets THEN ']' ELSE '[' END, input);
      IF(length = 0)
      THEN
        RETURN CONCAT(output, input);
      END IF;

      IF(in_brackets)
      THEN
        SET in_brackets = FALSE;
      ELSE
        SET output = CONCAT(output, SUBSTRING(input, 1, length - 1));
        SET in_brackets = TRUE;
      END IF;

      SET input = SUBSTRING(input, length + 1);
    END WHILE;
  END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Use UDF's (User Defined Functions)

Check this out https://launchpad.net/mysql-udf-regexp

So you just have to create your bracket matching regular expression and use the normal REPLACE statement with this function :)

Answer (score 0):

select try this:

```
SELECT REPLACE('abdcejkhh klhklhkl (abc) agjkk',SUBSTRING('abdcejkhh klhklhkl (abc) agjkk',POSITION('(' IN 'abdcejkhh klhklhkl (abc) agjkk'),(length('abdcejkhh klhklhkl (abc) agjkk')-POSITION(')' IN 'abdcejkhh klhklhkl (abc) agjkk'))),'')
```

Use this in update statement.